# How can I remove the left bar in the taglist plugin?

Tags: plugin-airline, plugin-taglist

How can I remove the left bar in the taglist plugin?
It is the gray part in picture.

[image: vim screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried setting `'foldcolumn'` to 0?

Comment: Thank you! inputting 'set foldcolumn=0' on Tlist commend line solved problem. but it's temporary. Whenever I create new Tlist, gray bar exist. I want to how remove gray bar to continue. I will search about 'fold' options.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the correct option:

1. Open `.vimrc`
2. Add `let Tlist_Enable_Fold_Column=0`

It's now good ;-)